# what is a meta model MXML and what's its goal

Tags: mxml, metamodel

Can someone please explain  what is meta model MXML?  Can we have a meta model MXML from a log file?  What's the goal of this meta model MXML? Does this meta model have a relationship with log files?

I've already searched through the net but I found a lot of information that I did not understand.